# Win 7 pin to task bar + launch4j + NSIS

Tags: java, windows, nsis, launch4j, taskbar

We struggle to make the Java Swing App named JabRef (http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) pinnable to the task bar of Windows. What we did so far:

- set the AppModelUserID in JabRef through JNA. We verified the correct value through output
- build fat jar and from this an executable (exe) with launch4j
- create an installer with NSIS using the WinShell plugin
- the installer creates a shortcut using the same AppModelUserID that is set in JabRef. We verified this via a hex editor.
- grouping works: you can start either via shortcut or exe
- what does NOT work: right-click on task bar item only shows "close application" action, nothing else.

Any ideas how to debug any further?

This shows the right-click menu. 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the right-click menu only has a single item? Please post a screen shot. When you are right-clicking the taskbar item, are you talking about your already running application window because clicking the shortcut would mean it is already pinned? What happens if you right-click the shortcut in the startmenu/screen, does it offer a pin option?

Comment: "We verified the correct value through output" What does this mean? Are you sure the Id is set correctly for your window and/or process?

Comment: The shortcut provides a pin to taskbar option, but if you start the app through the pinned taskbar entry, you basically have two icons on the task bar as the running instance is not grouped to the pinned icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pinned shortcut is not "taken over" by the application when you run it then the AppModelUserIDs are not set correctly.

You can verify the ID in a .lnk by using [this tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2013/09/24/shellproperty-exe-v2-read-all-properties-on-a-file-set-properties-of-certain-non-vt-lpwstr-types.aspx) (`shellproperty.exe read "System.AppUserModel.ID" from "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\MyApp.lnk"`)

In a running application the AppModelUserID can be set per window and/or on the process. Querying these is a bit harder for external apps but you can call them on yourself with `GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` and [`SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378430(v=vs.85).aspx).

If Windows thinks your application is a hosted app then it will hide the pin menu-item, see [Registering an Application as a Host Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459(v=vs.85).aspx#host). It [looks like](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6844541) Java applications are registered as a host process.

> If either the process itself or the shortcut file used to launch the
>   process has an explicit AppUserModelID, then the host process list is
>   ignored and the application is treated as a normal application by the
>   taskbar. The application's running windows are grouped together under
>   a single taskbar button and the application can be pinned to the
>   taskbar.

My only suggestion is to use JNA/JNI to call [`SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422(v=vs.85).aspx) in both your launcher application (if it is a separate process) and in your main application hosted by javaw.exe.

Comment: We use launch4j. I think this is the problem, as we cannot set the AppUserModelID in launch4j, only in the Java App that is wrapped by launch4j exe.

Comment: The latest `jna-platform` library now includes JNA bindings for `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/680